# PayFort Integration in swift

Tags: payfort

Not able to create PAYFORT Sandbox test account.Where I get merchant identifier number.

1. How to register PAYFORT test account
2. How to get the merchant_identifier
3. How to get the access_code
4. How to get the service_command

I do not have any Idea about PayPort.Please share any Example program related to Swift.From PAYFORT where I create the sandbox test account
"https://www.payfort.com/get-started/".From this link, I entered the personal details once complete the details try to login to PAYFORT, not able to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been facing similar questions and so emailed the PayFort support team. Here is the response I got:

> Good afternoon and thank you for contacting  PayFort.
>
> Please be advised that in order for you to have the account created
>   in the SANDBOX (https://testfort.payfort.com) environment, the first
>   contact has to be initiated by one of our Pre-Qualifications team
>   members after receiving a documented request in a form of registration
>   from our website. (www.payfort.com)
>
> The pre-qualification stage entails knowing the company/
>   organization's business and requirements. Qualifications are as
>   follows:
>
> The company has a legal setup in the countries mentioned on our
>   website. The company's business module is supported by PayFort.
>
> For more information about the businesses we support and countries,
>   please click on this link: http://www.payfort.com/payfort-faqs/
>
> After the qualification stage, one of our Sales Representative will
>   get in touch with you to get a deeper view of the business so as to
>   suggest the payment solution that would suit your requirements.
>
> Then only the TEST/SANDBOX account is created by our team to start the
>   Integration process.
>
> If you wish to proceed, please kindly register on the above link or
>   send a direct email to sales-uae@payfort.com.

Answer (score 0):

Register your self on https://www.payfort.com/get-started/ by giving your company info and wait for the email from PayFort. they'll send you the info about your test account.

you can login your test account on https://testfort.payfort.com and find your access code and merchant identifier from "Integeration Settings" menu and "Security Settings" option. you can also see the attached image [image] so you can easily find the access code and merchant identifier.

the service_command is a static value "PURCHASE" in capital letters.